# Аналог image.php для работы не только с локальным изображением

Tags: изображения, php

Надо делать ресайз картинок, но проблема в том, что картинки хранятся в виде ссылок. Какой есть аналог `image.php`, который может работать не только с локальным изображением?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скачиваете картинку по ссылке, и ресайзите ее своим image.php, в чем проблема?)

Написали бы хотя бы, какую задачу решаете)

Comment: у меня там много картинок будет выводиться, каждую качать что ли?

Comment: @Евгения Форманюк, а как вы представляете себе редактирование файла на чужом сервере?

Comment: @xEdelweiss я - никак, надо мной-студенткой сидит программист и говорит: делай так

Comment: @Евгения Форманюк, значит прислушайтесь к ответу @nolka и скачивайте изображения.

Comment: @xEdelweiss и всеж грустно( Пробую потом с программистом поговорить

Comment: @Евгения Форманюк, говорить можно с кем угодно о чём угодно, но другого способа просто не существует в природе. Варианты: 1) ваш программист вас троллит (ну, как "наточить якорь напильником") 2) вы чего-то не поняли 3) никакой он не программист.

Comment: Из опыта работы в комп. магазине "зачем мне видео скачивать я его только посмотрю и закрою". Вам в любом случае нужно будет получить картинку(скачать). После вы её сохраняете на сервере и даёте ссылку сценарию который будет изменять размер картнки.

Comment: @Андрей Аршинов, неправильные посетители! Правильные предложили бы посмотреть и обратно закачать :-)

Comment: Какой есть аналог image.php   -) А есть какойто единственный и всемизнаемый image.php?